# Fibonacci Sequence w/ infinitely nested radical

Tags: calculus, limits

One of my professors gave me a challenge problem that only one person in our class solved.

It went something like this:

What does $\sqrt{F_2^2 + \sqrt{F_4^2 + \sqrt{F_8^2 + \dots}}}\ $ approach, where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number.

Comment: This is a nice problem ! I think that I know the answer but no proof. In any manner (+1) for the question.

Comment: Use that $F_n^2+F_{2n+2}=F_{n+2}^2$. In particular $\sqrt{F_{2^n}^2+…}=F_{2^n+2}$